# How do I calculate the sine and cosine of a double in Java?

Tags: java, double, trigonometry, degrees

I'm trying to convert the sine of an angle from radians to degrees and I keep getting inaccurate numbers. My code looks like this:

```
public class PhysicsSolverAttempt2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] numbers = {60, 30, 0};
        double launchAngle = Double.parseDouble(numbers[0]);
        double iV = Double.parseDouble(numbers[1]);
        System.out.println(launchAngle);
        double iVV = iV * Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(launchAngle));
        System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(launchAngle)));
    }
}
```

When I use Math.sin(launchAngle), it gives me a perfect output in radians. However, when I convert the radians to degrees using the Math.toDegrees() function at the end, it gives me -17.464362139918286, though performing the same calculation with a calculator yields the number 0.86602540378. Am I using Math.toDegrees() incorrectly, or do I need to perform extra steps to get an accurate result?

Comment: What are you using to convert radians to degrees on your calculator?

Comment: Please clarify the question-- I don't know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: "though performing the same calculation with a calculator" - What calculation?

Comment: Irrelevant but why did you use Double.parseDouble()? The numbers array is already a Double array. Your unnecessarily casting a Double to a Double

Comment: You're looking for `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(launchAngle))`.

Comment: @amin29, the arguments were originally passed into the method using the args tab at the top of browxy. I initialized an array so that you could see it here on stack overflow, and so I wouldn't have people  saying that my problem was that I didn't have the array initialized.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.sin()` accepts only radians as it's input. It appears your trying to find the sin of `launchAngle`, which is in degrees.

`Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(launchAngle)));`

Answer (score 0):

The sine function returns the y-coordinate of a point on the unit circle. For `Math.sin`, you input an angle in radians and it returns the corresponding y-coordinate. However, what you are doing here is using the result of `Math.sin` (a y-coordinate, not an angle) as the argument for `Math.toDegrees`, which is supposed to convert radians to degrees. I assume the intention was to find the sin of the `launchAngle`. If so, turn

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(launchAngle))
```

into

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(launchAngle))
```

Comment: Sorry, I see how I was unclear. I meant that calling Math.toDegrees on the output of Math.sin is almost certainly not what he intends to be doing, as Math.sin doesn't return an angle in radians, it returns the y coordinate of a point on the unit circle. I'll edit it.

Comment: I think you've got a really good point here. That must be what I was missing. I still see one problem, though: The result I get from that last System.out.println() is -17.464362139918286, which isn't a point on the unit circle. Do you have any idea why I'm getting this number if I'm supposed to be getting the y-coordinate?

Comment: You aren't getting the y-coordinate, actually. Notice you're calling `Math.toDegrees` on the result of `Math.sin`. This means it thinks that the y-coordinate returned from `Math.sin` is a value in radians, and it's blindly doing a conversion from that value into degrees.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest way to find an accurate measurement is to simply multiply the initial degree measurement by Math.PI/180 and to use that number for calculations.

From there, Math.sin(launchAngle) will give clean, workable results.

Comment: That's the same thing as doing `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(launchAngle))`, and I'd argue that the latter is more readable.